# Intent not opening a specific folder

Tags: android, android-intent, android-external-storage

I have a question and also a problem, using this code to open a specific folder, the **Recent** folder opens to me, but I want to open "**MyFolder**" directly. I tried to find the correct answer in this forum and went all over the net but I had no success, can anyone help, thanks.

```
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyFolder" + File.separator);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(root);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(android.content.Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
```

IMPORTANT:

Information for all people who have the same problem, the only solution is File Picker, and focus on that, Intent is not the solution !!! It was just with the help of File Picker that I opened a specific folder with a single click and listed my text files. Examples: https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=filepicker Cheers!

Comment: `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` does not take a `Uri` as input. You can use `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`, but that requires a document `Uri`, not one from a file.

Comment: If you can write the whole code, it would be good for the others as a lot of them have a dilemma. Thank you.

Comment: There cannot be "the whole code". You are trying to do something (use the Storage Access Framework for something outside of that framework) that is not supported. Also, the directory that you want will not exist on Android 10+ devices, unless the user created that directory themselves. I recommend that you drop the "open a specific folder" idea.

Comment: The user creates that folder.

Comment: Then you can use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to allow the user to choose whatever folder they like, after which you can use that folder for putting in your own content and sub-trees.

Comment: When I used ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, app crashes

Comment: If you wanted, you could ask a separate Stack Overflow question, with a [mcve] including the code that you tried and the stack trace that you got.

Comment: Information for all people who have the same problem, the only solution is File Picker, and focus on that, Intent is not the solution !!! It was just with the help of File Picker that I opened a specific folder with a single click and listed my text files. Examples: https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=filepicker  Cheers!

Comment: Note that those will not work on Android 10 (by default) or Android R+ (for most, if not all apps). [Most apps will no longer have access to the filesystem](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html).

Comment: That's not exactly true, why, because File Picker in my case is used internally in my app and it doesn't depend on the SDK version. What you're saying is generally, I'm talking about a specific example! Otherwise, I tested on devices, not on the emulator, from Android 6 to Android 9.1.0.266.

Comment: "because File Picker in my case is used internally in my app and it doesn't depend on the SDK version" -- if you cannot access the files, you cannot display them in a file-picking library. Hence, a file picker does depend on the Android version of the device that is running your app. There are specific places in the filesystem for which your app has filesystem access, even on Android 10+. You get those locations via methods on `Context`, such as `getFilesDir()` and `getExternalFilesDir()`. If you can keep your file picker within those locations, it should work fine.

Comment: Finally we understand and it makes me happy that, I can select files from a specific directory and, of course, copy the contents of any created internal .txt from my app into the textview of my app. That means everything works smoothly ... it remains to be seen what will happen in the future. For now my problem is solved and advice to others if they have the same problem.